# Not able connect flyway migration with postgresSQL in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I'm setting up the `flyway` migration for the `spring-boot` project with `PostgreSQL` but not able to connect with the database and getting below exception.

> Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:6.0.8:migrate (default-cli) on project open-feign: **org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password! -> [Help 1]**

**Spring boot version :** 2.2.1.RELEASE

**Maven :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.8</version>
</plugin>
```

**application.yml**

```
    spring:
      application:
        name: MIGRATE DEMO
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DABASENAME
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: postgres
        password: root
        platform: postgres
        dbcp2:
          validation-query: SELECT 1
      jpa:
        datbase: POSTGRESQL
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
        show-sql: true
        generate-ddl: true
        properties:
          hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: validate

    flyway:
      user: postgres
      password: root
      schemas: DABASENAME
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DABASENAME
      locations: filesystem:db/migration
```

Thanks In-advance

Comment: You can remove the flyway plugin and also the version on the flyway dependency then you can also remove the flyway configuration. Spring Boot will do the rest

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks for the response, I tried same error i'm getting. 
 **org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!**

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: `[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.319 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-19T16:15:39+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:6.0.8:migrate (default-cli) on project migrate-demo: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password! -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is working, below changes I made.

As per FlywayAutoConfiguration spring.flyway is expecting e.g.

```
spring.flyway:
```

Not able to read properties like below

```
spring: 
    flyway: 
        user: ....
```

Versioning format `Vx.x__(description) [V(capital letter) 1.2(integer)__(two underscore characters)]`